# Scala slick idiomaticity and transcending table definition boilerplate

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

While Scala set out to unwind the boilerplate practices of Java (and some other things like immutability, first-class functional programming, etc. before that) the slick library tutorial suggests a lot of boilerplate around simple table definition:

```
  class MyTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, String, String)](tag, "MyTable") {
    def Col1 = column[String]("Col1")
    def Col2 = column[String]("Col2")
    def Col3 = column[String]("Col3")
    def * = (Col1, Col2, Col3)
  }
```

I could hardly call that api usage example anywhere near idiomatic; It is easy to enumerate all the duplications in the above derived working code - for the table name, the column types, the column names. I find it hard to imagine using this style for defining a larger schema with any kind of elegance in my code base.

What is your favorite way of reducing this into something where all these duplications and verbosity are no longer necessary? Is slick code generation the only antidote?

[I found this](http://slick.typesafe.com/talks/2013-12-03_Scala-eXchange/2013-12-03_Patterns-for-Slick-database-applications-Scala-eXchange.pdf) but sometimes I really prefer to focus on application logic more than diving into the the mind dumps of library creators, generous as their contribution may be. Don't get me wrong, I think slick is very cool, it's just that this amount of boilerplate must be a naive example that could be much simplified somehow...